# How to redirect by using the HTTP_REFERER

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using CentOS 7.4/Apache 2.4.6.

How do I create the redirect setting by using HTTP_REFERER like below rule?

http://example.jp/aa/aa/homepage/test01.html

When user goes to http://example.jp/bb.html,

if bb/bb/homepage/test01.html　would exist, he/she goes to 
  http://example.jp/bb/bb/homepage/test01.html

else (it means bb/bb/homepage/test01.html not exist) , he/she goes to 
  http://example.jp/bb/bb/homepage.html

I would like to set the redirection for all path same as test01.html.

Comment: You can access the `HTTP_REFERER` in a `RewriteCond`, that also allows you to capture parts of that string. You can refer to such captures using a %-Notation. Please see the official documentation of the apache rewriting module for details. That documentation is of excellent quality and comes with helpful examples.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If you know, could you share the page including the sample codes on apache official site?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html